# two .so files couldn't load from two different package in an application why?

Tags: android, android-activity

> i have two .so file one is in following folder Armeabi,armeabi-v7a,Mips,x86 and other is in arm64-v8a,mips64,x86-64 , I need to load these two .so files from different packages inside application but one of the .so files doesn't loaded and creates error why ?

Comment: Please run the `file` command on each of the `.so` files and edit your question to give the result (and show the exact `.so` files you are talking about)

Comment: i run the command from terminal in ubuntu and from this .so file was create i have android.mk file inside this i enter two lines like this LOCAL_MODULE    := splpro-jni LOCAL_SRC_FILES := splpro.c where entries of previously created .so files was there but why it is not get output ??

Answer (score 0):

Read [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) and [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html).

You may want to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, or configure `/etc/ld.so.conf` then run `ldconfig`

In both cases, you want the two *directories* (Linux -including Android- has directories, not "folders") containing your `.so` [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared object files to appear.

Read also [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) & [Drepper's paper: *How To Write A Shared Library*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)